# Use NPM Package Typings With A Global Module Imported In Script Tags

Tags: typescript

I'm importing a library into my html page using script tags instead of importing it in as a module and using webpack, but I still want to have strong typings for the module. The npm package includes typings in it so I've npm installed it into my project as a dev dependency. I don't know how to declare the module as globally available so I can use it as a value in scripts. The package is date-fns and it has a typings document with an interface and a module declaration. https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/typings.d.ts

I've tried adding a global.d.ts file with the following:

```
type dateFns = import('date-fns');
```

but this creates a duplicate identifier of dateFns and also the error `Module 'date-fns' does not refer to a type, but is used as a type here.`

I want to be able to just start using the module like:

*App.js*

```
dateFns.addWeeks(new Date(), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've since found the answer to this. You can either add the following in a global.d.ts file:

```
declare const dateFns: typeof import('date-fns');
```

or in your module you can use

```
declare global {
  const dateFns: typeof import('date-fns');
}
```